# What is "lights-out systems"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "lights-out systems" mean in

> While agile might not be suitable for building safety-critical and lights-out
>   systems, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Supposedly](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/lights-out-management):

> Lights-out management (LOM) is the ability for a system administrator to monitor and manage servers by remote control. A complete LOM system consists of a hardware component called the LOM module and a program that facilitates the continuous monitoring of variables such as microprocessor temperature and utilization. The program also allows for such remote operations as rebooting, shutdown, troubleshooting, alarm setting, fan-speed control, and operating system reinstallation.

How much research did you do into your question, and why did you think this was the place for it?

Comment: More generally lights-out is a facility/plant/installation with no onsite staff, ie totally automatic and so the system must be highly reliable